# swap rows and columns with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here is what I got …

```
>>> v = [[x for x in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
>>> h = [[x for x in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
>>> v
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
>>> for i in range(len(v[0])):
>>>    for j in range(len(v[0])):
>>>        h[j][i] = v[i][j]
...        
>>> h
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

How can I generate h with list comprehension instead of the nested for loops?

**UPDATE:**

Thank you all for your awesome answers and I apologize for not being more clear in my original post.  I should have initialized `v` like so:

```
>>> v = [[randint(0,10) for x in range(4)] for x in range(4)]
```

For instance `v` is:

```
>>> v
[[5, 1, 0, 5], [8, 9, 9, 10], [3, 7, 1, 1], [6, 6, 10, 7]]
>>> for i in range(len(v[0])):
>>>    for j in range(len(v[0])):
>>>        h[j][i] = v[i][j]
...     
>>> h
[[5, 8, 3, 6], [1, 9, 7, 6], [0, 9, 1, 10], [5, 10, 1, 7]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a list comprehension, you can `zip`:

```
list(map(list,zip(*v)))

# [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

If it's ok to have a list of tuples, you can omit the `map`:

```
list(zip(*v))
# [(0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: If you omit `map` no need use the `list`.

Answer (score 1):

if you must use list comprehensions:

```
[[y for x in range(4)] for y in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With a straightforward comprehension:

```
h = [ v[j][i] for i in range(4) for j in range(4)  ]
```